# How can i optimize the size of my JS file After WebPack ? (VUEJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

My JS file after WebPack is 6.53 Mb. The Application has 20 components and  many features.

Do you think i can reduce the size ?  Any Orientations ?

Thank you.

Comment: `Any Orientations` portrait or landscape? `Do you think i can reduce the size` - no, but what would I know, I don't have your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My JS file after WebPack is 6.53 Mb

You're question is not apparent but I am interpreting this as your project is in development mode.

Well, there are lot of optimizations you can do to reduce your bundle size using methods like gzip compression.

For vue, gzip compression can be achieved dynamically using the following code in `vue.config.js`:

```
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin")

let plugins = []

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    const compressionTest = /\.(js|css|html|ico)(\?.*)?$/i
    plugins = [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: "gzip",
            compressionOptions: {
                numiterations: 15
            },
            minRatio: 0.99,
            test: compressionTest
        })
    ]
}
module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins
    }
}
```

Now, when you run `yarn build`, gzip files should be generated automatically.

Moreover, you can use [PurgeCSS](https://www.purgecss.com/) to remove unused css in your project. You could also use [CSS Modules](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules) to shorten up your css class names.

Example configuration for css modules in `vue.config.js` would be:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        requireModuleExtension: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        loaderOptions: {
            css: {
                localsConvention: "camelCaseOnly",
                modules: {
                    localIdentName:
                        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
                            ? "[hash:base64:5]"
                            : "app-[hash:base64:5]-[local]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html#usage

You could also use [Functional Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) where you think state is not necessary. Since, functional components doesn't handle any state, you should gain some optimizations. This is negligble in small projects but should help in big projects.

I hope this helps!